# UHF-Rfid in day-today cards

Tags: rfid

I am a total newbie to rfid-tech. Well, i know the basics, but i guess asking this here might be cheaper than buy something to see it doesent work :-).

I'm wondering if any rfid day-to-day cards like banking, time- and/or accesscontrol, transportation etc. are uhf-cards and able to communicate on a long(er) distance (meters instead of centimeters)?
I'd like to count people based on rfid-mesurments, the antenna would be at the entrance of a room (and yes, im aware that one could own more than one :))

Thank you in advance
Chris

Comment: I think this question should be asked on the [Electrical Engineering SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com) as it's not programming related.

Answer (score 0):

Most day to day cards are not UHF-based (yet). They typically would be HF RFID, providing only short reading distances. If you would look for UHF labels, those are mainly used in apparel retail and vehicle identification use cases. Here the long reading distance is a requirement. UHF RFID is just a more recent and newer technology compared to HF, and not that common yet.

Comment: You should also be aware that UHF - at a frequency of around 900MHz - is influenced by a human body. That means, depending where someone carries a UHF tag, the communication can be difficult or impossible.